# Is += an atomic operation in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a data aggregation object on a multi-thread environment, and I have the following situation:

```
int counts;

// This event is triggered by many threads at the same time
public void OnDataReceived(DataEvent evt)
{
   counts += evt.counts;
}
```

My question is whether it is safe to do

```
counts += evt.counts;
```

or I need something like

```
lock(lockObject)
{
   counts += evt.counts;
}
```

Comment: += is *not* an atomic operation. You should use Interlocked.Increment.

Comment: Nope. By the way, whether a particular operation in .NET is guaranteed to be atomic does not only depend on the operation itself, but also on the data type it is applied to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` is not an atomic operation. You should use the [Interlocked.Increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.8) method.